# integer assigning in java

Tags: java, integer

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 0153;
        int b=a;
        System.out.println(""+b);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why it prints `107` and not `153`?

Comment: Because `0153` is assumed to be an octal number.

Comment: @Lion is right. Refer to the "Integer Literals" section of the Java spec here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

Answer (score 2):

Octal of 107 is 0153

In Java you can create octal literals simply by adding a leading zero like this: int a = 0755; Be careful! It is very common to specify an octal literal

Answer (score 0):

Because a number starting by `0` is considered as an octal value in Java. `0153` in octal is `107` in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You write as octal and print defaults to decimal.

```
         Input                            Prints (decimal)

Decimal   153                             153
         ^
         No leading zero (digits 0-9) 

Octal    0153                             107
         ^
         leading zero (digits 0-7)

Hex      0x153                            339
         ^^
         leading 0x (digits 0-F)
```